Recorder recording returns null duration and can't play
I'm currently working on implementing a audio recording functionality and I'm using the Recorder https://pub.dev/packages/record library and I'm having issues playing the recorded audio using this Audio Players library  https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers

The media file shows up on my device storage and I can play it using my media player but it doesn't play at all using the library in the app ..

I keep getting state exception (Bad state: no element )

I also noticed one of the log messages was MPEGWriter: media might not be streamable but I ignored it since the media file shows up and plays using local media player

Whenever I play the media file using local media player, it doesn't show the duration at all


here's the player widget;
class RecordingsView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  final Function startRecording;
  const RecordingsView({super.key, required this.startRecording});

  @override
  ConsumerState<RecordingsView> createState() => _RecordingsViewState();
}

class _RecordingsViewState extends ConsumerState<RecordingsView> {
  final dbHelper = AppDatabase.instance();
  late StreamProvider<List<DataItems?>> allEntriesStreamProvider;
  // late FutureProvider<List<int?>> entriesSize; works
  // late StreamProvider<int?> entriesSize; works
  late FutureProvider<Map<String, dynamic>?> entriesSizeProvider;
  final playbackProvider = ChangeNotifierProvider<PlayBackState>((ref) {
    return PlayBackState();
  });
 AudioPlayer audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  requestPermission() async {
    final micPerm = await Permission.microphone.request();
    if (micPerm.isGranted) {
      widget.startRecording();
    }
    if (micPerm.isDenied) {
      showPermsDeniedDialog();
    }
  }
  }

 

  startPlaying({required String path}) async {
    if (audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.playing) {
      //pause audio
      await audioPlayer.stop();
      audioPlayer.dispose();
    } else {
      audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
      // audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.release);
    }

    await audioPlayer.play(DeviceFileSource(path));
    final duration = await audioPlayer.getDuration();
    print("REC_VALUE: duration-> $duration");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final allEntries = ref.watch(allEntriesStreamProvider);
    final playBackState = ref.watch(playbackProvider);

    if (playBackState.journalEntityData != null) {
      final playBackEntry = playBackState.journalEntityData!;
      final prevId = playBackState.prevId;

      if (playBackEntry.id != prevId) {
        //start audio
        final trimmed = playBackEntry.audioFile.replaceFirst("/", "").trim();
        startPlaying(path: trimmed);
      } else if (audioPlayer.state == PlayerState.playing) {
        //pause audio
        audioPlayer.pause();
      } else {
        //play audio
        audioPlayer.resume();
      }
    }

    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      ref.read(playbackProvider).updatePlayerState(playerState: state);
    });

    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          //title & settings Icon row,
          //time/date column
          DateTimeHeader(timeStamp: DateTime.now()),
          Expanded(
            child: allEntries.when(
              data: (data) {
                return NestedListView.builder(
                    wantKeepAlive: true,
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) => Recording(
                          entry: data[index],
                          updateRecordingView: (entry) {
                            ref.read(playbackProvider)
                              .updatePlayBackItem(journalEntityData:entry);
                          },
                          currentId:
                              ref.watch(playbackProvider).journalEntityData?.id,
                        ));
              },
              error: (error, stackTrace) {
                return const Center(
                  child: Text("Some error occured",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: CustomColorsLight.viewColorSecondary,
                          fontSize: 24.0)),
                );
              },
              loading: () {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              },
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 36.0),
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: InitRecording(
              updateRecordingView: () async {
                final micPerm = await Permission.microphone.status;
                if (micPerm.isGranted) {
                  widget.startRecording();
                  
                }

                if (micPerm.isDenied) {
                  requestPermission();
                }
                if (micPerm.isPermanentlyDenied) {
                  openAppSettings();
                }
              },
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

here's the recording widget;
final recordingStateProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<RecordingStateNotifier>((ref) {
  return RecordingStateNotifier();
});

class RecordingScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const RecordingScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<RecordingScreen> createState() => _RecordingScreenState();
}

class _RecordingScreenState extends ConsumerState<RecordingScreen> {
  late AudioRecorder recorder;

  Future<String?> audioRecordingPath() async {
    var status = await Permission.storage.status;
    if (status.isDenied) {
      final req = await Permission.storage.request();
      if (req.isGranted) {
        final path = await createDirectory();
        return path;
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }

    if (status.isGranted) {
      final path = await createDirectory();
      return path;
    }

    if (status.isPermanentlyDenied) {
      openAppSettings();
    }

    return null;
  }

  Future<String> createDirectory() async {
    Directory directory = Directory("");
    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      directory = Directory("/storage/emulated/0/Download/audio");
      final dirExists = await directory.exists();
      if (!dirExists) {
        directory.create(recursive: true);
      }
    } else {
      directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    }

    return directory.path;
  }

  startRecording() async {
    final path = await audioRecordingPath();
    if (path != null) {
      recorder = AudioRecorder();
      final dateFormat = DateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss_a");
      await recorder.start(const RecordConfig(),
          path: "$path/${dateFormat.format(DateTime.now())}.m4a");
      ref
          .read(recordingStateProvider)
          .updateState(recordingState: RecordingState.start);
    } else {
      print("PATH is NULL");
    }
  }
   stopRecording() async { 
     await recorder.stop();

ref.read(recordingStateProvider).updateState(recordingState: RecordingState.stop);
 } 



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final recordingState = ref.watch(recordingStateProvider);

    return Stack(children: [
      RecordingsView(startRecording: () {
        startRecording();
      },stopRecording:(){
        stopRecording();
}),
      if (recordingState.recordingState != RecordingState.stop) ...{
        RecordView(recorder: recorder)
      },
    ]);
  }
}


I've looked around and I haven't found any solution or issue that mentions any of this, I followed the implementation form the docs and other relevant materials to the T. But I can't seem to get what's causing this
